# Formatting string in textbox on asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Sorry if my question is double, I just don't know how to ask it on google, thanks for understanding...

For my question : 
I have asp:textbox and I want the text to be like xxx-xxxxxx.
x can be any number. 
How can I do it without running the server?
Can I do it without writing new JavaScript code?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Id" runat="server" placeHolder="Your ID" style="width:100%" MaxLength="10" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258709/mask-textbox-view-for-a-phone-number

Comment: Are you want to mask textbox input to a phone number with JS? There is an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096370/phone-mask-in-asp-net.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. That is exactly what I want to  
You know any way to do it without JS?
To add regex into property or something like it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this too many external libraries are available you can use [Telrik ajax lib](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/maskedtextbox/overview/defaultcs.aspx) you can follow following method to make that
First, include the jQuery and masked input javascript files.

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Next, call the mask function for those items you wish to have masked.

```
jQuery(function($){
$("#phone").mask("999-9999999");
});
```

Optionally, if you are not satisfied with the underscore ('_') character as a placeholder, you may pass an optional argument to the maskedinput method.

```
jQuery(function($){
$("#phone").mask("999-9999999",{placeholder:" "});
});
```

Optionally, if you would like to execute a function once the mask has been completed, you can specify that function as an optional argument to the maskedinput method.

```
jQuery(function($){
 $("#phone").mask("999-9999999",{completed:function(){alert("You typed the 
  following: "+this.val());}});
 });
```

You can have part of your mask be optional. Anything listed after '?' within the mask is considered optional user input. The common example for this is phone number + optional extension.

```
jQuery(function($){
  $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999? x99999");
});
```

If your requirements aren't met by the predefined placeholders, you can always add your own. For example, maybe you need a mask to only allow hexadecimal characters. You can add your own definition for a placeholder, say 'h', like so: $.mask.definitions['h'] = "[A-Fa-f0-9]"; Then you can use that to mask for something like css colors.

```
jQuery(function($){
 $("#phone").mask("#hhhhhh");
});
```

By design, this plugin will reject input which doesn't complete the mask. You can bypass this by using a '?' character at the position where you would like to consider input optional. For example, a mask of "(999) 999-9999? x99999" would require only the first 10 digits of a phone number with extension being optional.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am looking for the fastest way (on run time) to do it.
And I not sure if Telrik ajax lib is open source for any use...

Answer (score 0):

Try this in SQL Server:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(x.SecurityNumber,1,3) + 'xxxxx' +  SUBSTRING(x.SecurityNumber,LEN(x.SecurityNumber) - 2, LEN(x.SecurityNumber))     AS column1 FROM underlyingTable x
```